# OpenVPN with Azure VPN Gateway disconnects at least once a minute

Tags: azure, openvpn

I have got a VPN connection using OpenVPN and OpenVPN Connect to an Azure VPN Gateway (Gateway for virtual networks). Its a certificate based Point 2 Site setup. The connection works except for the fact that it disconnects and reconnect literally every freaking minute (I am not exaggerating)!

This is the log from the OpenVPN Connect client (I removed public IP Addresses and URL's for privacy reasons).

```
29.4.2021, 10:54:40 Session invalidated: KEEPALIVE_TIMEOUT
⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:40 Client terminated, restarting in 2000 ms...
⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:40 SetupClient: signaling tun destroy event
⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:42 EVENT: RECONNECTING ⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:42 EVENT: RESOLVE ⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:42 EVENT: WAIT ⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:42 WinCommandAgent: transmitting bypass route to ---
{
    "host" : "---",
    "ipv6" : false
}

⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:42 Connecting to [---]:443 (---) via TCPv4
⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:42 EVENT: CONNECTING ⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:42 Tunnel Options:V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1523,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_CLIENT,keydir 1,cipher AES-256-GCM,auth [null-digest],keysize 256,tls-auth,key-method 2,tls-client
⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:42 Creds: UsernameEmpty/PasswordEmpty
⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:42 Peer Info:
IV_VER=3.git::58b92569
IV_PLAT=win
IV_NCP=2
IV_TCPNL=1
IV_PROTO=2
IV_AUTO_SESS=1
IV_GUI_VER=OCWindows_3.2.3-1851
IV_SSO=openurl

⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:42 SSL Handshake: CN=---, TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:42 Session is ACTIVE
⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:42 EVENT: GET_CONFIG ⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:42 Sending PUSH_REQUEST to server...
⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:42 EVENT: ASSIGN_IP ⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:42 OPTIONS:
0 [route] [10.0.1.0] [255.255.255.0] 
1 [route] [10.0.0.0] [255.255.255.0] 
2 [route-gateway] [10.0.3.1] 
3 [topology] [subnet] 
4 [ifconfig] [10.0.3.3] [255.255.255.0] 
5 [cipher] [AES-256-GCM] 

⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:42 PROTOCOL OPTIONS:
  cipher: AES-256-GCM
  digest: NONE
  compress: NONE
  peer ID: -1
⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:42 CAPTURED OPTIONS:
Session Name: ---
Layer: OSI_LAYER_3
Remote Address: ---
Tunnel Addresses:
  10.0.3.3/24 -> 10.0.3.1
Reroute Gateway: IPv4=0 IPv6=0 flags=[ IPv4 ]
Block IPv6: no
Add Routes:
  10.0.1.0/24
  10.0.0.0/24
Exclude Routes:
DNS Servers:
Search Domains:

⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:43 SetupClient: transmitting tun setup list to \\.\pipe\agent_ovpnconnect
{
    "confirm_event" : "080c000000000000",
    "destroy_event" : "fc0b000000000000",
    "tun" : 
    {
        "adapter_domain_suffix" : "",
        "add_routes" : 
        [
            {
                "address" : "10.0.1.0",
                "gateway" : "",
                "ipv6" : false,
                "metric" : -1,
                "net30" : false,
                "prefix_length" : 24
            },
            {
                "address" : "10.0.0.0",
                "gateway" : "",
                "ipv6" : false,
                "metric" : -1,
                "net30" : false,
                "prefix_length" : 24
            }
        ],
        "block_ipv6" : false,
        "layer" : 3,
        "mtu" : 0,
        "remote_address" : 
        {
            "address" : "---",
            "ipv6" : false
        },
        "reroute_gw" : 
        {
            "flags" : 256,
            "ipv4" : false,
            "ipv6" : false
        },
        "route_metric_default" : -1,
        "session_name" : "---",
        "tunnel_address_index_ipv4" : 0,
        "tunnel_address_index_ipv6" : -1,
        "tunnel_addresses" : 
        [
            {
                "address" : "10.0.3.3",
                "gateway" : "10.0.3.1",
                "ipv6" : false,
                "metric" : -1,
                "net30" : false,
                "prefix_length" : 24
            }
        ]
    },
    "wintun" : false
}
POST np://[\\.\pipe\agent_ovpnconnect]/tun-setup : 200 OK
TAP ADAPTERS:
guid='{B8EEBC7D-DB5C-4060-9588-97ECEE24AE24}' index=22 name='Local Area Connection'
Open TAP device "Local Area Connection" PATH="\\.\Global\{B8EEBC7D-DB5C-4060-9588-97ECEE24AE24}.tap" SUCCEEDED
TAP-Windows Driver Version 9.24
ActionDeleteAllRoutesOnInterface iface_index=22
netsh interface ip set interface 22 metric=1
Ok.
netsh interface ip set address 22 static 10.0.3.3 255.255.255.0 gateway=10.0.3.1 store=active
IPHelper: add route 10.0.1.0/24 22 10.0.3.1 metric=-1
IPHelper: add route 10.0.0.0/24 22 10.0.3.1 metric=-1
ipconfig /flushdns
Windows IP Configuration
Successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.
TAP handle: 340d000000000000
⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:43 Connected via TUN_WIN
⏎29.4.2021, 10:54:43 EVENT: CONNECTED ---:443 (---) via /TCPv4 on TUN_WIN/10.0.3.3/ gw=[10.0.3.1/]⏎
```

Does anyone have a clue what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, but I get the same behavior on my Azure Certificate configured VPN. It does however seem that if you go back to using the v2 of the OpenVPN program, that is much simpler. It connects and stays connected without issue. I know Azure wouldn't be disconnecting you on purpose from their side.

I would check your OpenVPN version.

There are 3 versions (2 still in use today and being released) that could have something to do with it. ^_^

1. v3 - Dubbed "OpenVPN Connect" URL here: https://openvpn.net/downloads/openvpn-connect-v3-windows.msi
2. v2 - Dubbed "OpenVPN Connect Client" URL here: https://openvpn.net/downloads/openvpn-connect-v2-windows.msi

[Picture of explanation of Versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsZ1k.png)

[Showing the download of v3 and v2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NFcr.png)

Downloads can be found on their downloads page. *"Not to be confused with the Community Edition downloads page."* Or as Shown above.
[Click either Download to download the latest v3 version or Click on the Alternate Versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP4M2.png)

I noticed version 3.2.1 was perfect for some folks. As soon as I updated to 3.3.X, our Azure wouldn't even connect because it couldn't verify the certificate. Happy Trails!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue and my best effort work around after seeing the "Session invalidated: KEEPALIVE_TIMEOUT" log message was to send a constant non stop ping "-t" to the OpenVPN server to keep the traffic alive. Works like a charm but I am giving it the "ping of death" to keep it alive!

Answer (score 0):

I had identical issue with my setup (Virtual network gateway in azure, OpenVPN Connect 3.3.6.2752 as client).
Problem with server verification can be solved by removing line starting with verify-x509-name from opvn configuration. (Mind it will disable verification of server side, probably not the best solution for production environment!)
Problem with dis/reconnection every minute was solved by adding "keepalive 0 0" to my .ovpn client config.